# Some requested document was not found.-firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

in my flutter app i need to create a new document and create and set value to a newfield in firestore,when the user creates an account. when user creates his account i call `await Database().updateusername(email);` which is

```
Future updateusername(String username) async {
    final DocumentReference Docreference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Songs").doc(username);
    return await Docreference.update({"Username": username});
  }
```

but i get this error

> cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.

my firestore version is **^0.14.0+2**

can someone help me on this issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the document you build a reference to was not found for update.  You can't [update()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html) a document that doesn't exist.  According to that linked API documentation:

> If no document exists yet, the update will fail.

If you want to create a document if it doesn't exist, you will need to use [set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) instead of update.  If you want to be able to create a document if it doesn't exist, or update it if it does already exist, you should pass `SetOptions.merge` as the second parameter, as explained by the API documentation.

Comment: But actually it exists in my case! Checked it double!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do an if else to check whether the document is exists or not like:

```
var a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("collection_name")
        .doc("documentname")
        .get();
if (a.exists) {
      final DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("collection_name")
          .doc("documentname");
      return await documentReference.update({
        //your data
      });
    } else {
      final DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("collection_name")
          .doc("documentname");
      return await documentReference.set({
       //your data
      });
```

Comment: It's still possible for the document to become deleted between the calls to get and update, which will make the update fail.  The only way to do this safely is with a transaction.